# postmessage and webservices, possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postmessage

I have a page that loads an iframe with another domain. Pages are communicating via postmessage. I would like for the page in the iframe to communicate with the server. I tried using a webservice but then I get

Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame.

As I see it, the page inside the iframe tries to call it's own server, should this not be possible? I tried wrapping in a setTimeout but no luck.

Yes, the origin is the parent window but the call was done via postmessage.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: *I tried wrapping in a setTimeout but no luck* Why would it work? Also, it's a bit unclear which domain the iframe is on, which domain the webservice is on, from where you are calling the webservice and how you are calling the webservice.

Comment: The webservice is called from inside the iframe and also has the same domain as the iframe. It's called via jquery,  $.ajax.

Comment: Sorry if this is a bit off, I'm not an expert in this. As a starting point I would look into jsonp, and I did a search on 'cross domain ajax request' and got some links that looked helpful.

Comment: Yeah that is the path I went down, not ideal but it will probably do the trick.